# What's the connection between a spoon (匕) and the old age (⺹)? (Kanji: 老)

Tags: kanji, etymology, questions, radicals

I was studying some radicals and I found this: ⺹ (old, old-age) and this: 匕. But why this: 老 (old + spoon) means "old man, old age, grow old"?? 
Do Japaneses think a spoon can make you older in a shorter time?
Should I stop using spoons and start to use only chopsticks?

Please help me clearifying all these doubts floating in my mind xD
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 8):

It appears that the 匕 component that we see in 老 did not start out as the same character as 匕 "spoon", but instead as a stylization of long hair and a cane.  This is more apparent if you compare the progression of forms from ancient Shang inscriptions through to the modern shapes: see the [匕 glyph origin at Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8C%95#Glyph_origin), the [老 glyph origin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%80%81#Glyph_origin), and by way of comparison, the [比 glyph origin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AF%94#Glyph_origin), where the 匕 component again developed from a non-"spoon" origin.

When exploring the origins of Chinese characters, it's important to recognize that the modern forms are not necessarily indicative of the original forms.  Things change over time, and there's a general trend towards simplification and standardization.

If you're really interested in the historical development of Chinese characters, look into getting a good character dictionary.  I've heard good things about the [大漢和辞典 (*Dai Kan-Wa Jiten*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dai_Kan-Wa_Jiten), a serious and large monolingual Japanese resource.  For English readers looking for a starter character etymology dictionary, I found Kenneth Henshall's [*A Guide to Remembering Japanese Characters*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0804820384) to be pretty good.  Avoid anything by Heisig, however: he provides fanciful descriptions of each kanji that might be helpful for memorizing, but that have nothing to do with historical development.

Comment: That 比 explanation on Wiktionary is not correct, compare the component in 比 with [人](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%BA#Chinese) and then 匕 again. I will concede the differences are rather small, so then we should look at it from another angle: [匕]{/*pijʔ/ > ひ} is a phonetic component in [比]{ /*pij-s/ > ひ}

Comment: @droooze, I'd be more apt to view 比 as semantic + phonetic if the two components in the oldest forms of 比 weren't identical.  I'm not 100% sold on the theory that the character is composed of two 人; as you note, the component variants in the Shang script are facing opposite directions in the two characters 人 and 比, and the component in 比 seems to have an additional shape element (the upward tick at the end of the shorter "leg").  That said, neither of the two identical components in 比 appear to be 匕 either, at least at the Shang stage -- unless that uptick is irrelevant?

Comment: You can contrast 比 with [从](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BB%8E). Well it seems that Wiktionary doesn't have enough glyph forms! Shang forms of [匕](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=17) were characterised by one or both of the following features: (1) the "uptick", and (2) the bottom/longer leg was curled backwards slightly. The *facing direction* is not a characteristic, and both [人](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=9) and 匕 faced either direction.

Comment: The differences between 人 and 匕 were greatly eroded later, possibly contributing to them eventually being standardised with different facing directions, and contributing to the fall in use of 从 and the rise of the more complex variant 從.

Comment: @droooze, excellent additional info, thank you!  Some of the other Shang-era versions you posted and linked to make me think more of a bent fork or similar implement -- interesting that none show a closed-circle shape on the end of a stick, which is more what I'd expect for a "spoon, ladle" sense.  Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The other answer is correct. What you see as「匕」is a corruption of a walking-cane shape, not *spoon*, and you shouldn't break down「老」into two separate components.

「老」(*old*) depicts an *old, decrepit person* with long, unkempt hair, hunched over a walking stick.

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[前2](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)・2.6
[合集36416](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=36416&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
殳季良父壺
[集成9713](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9713&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
秦律雜抄32
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

> As「老」is ultimately a depiction of a *person*, the core shape originally contained「人」. For reference:
>
> <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)・2940
> [合集18901](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=18901&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
> 簡・[帛](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_Silk_Manuscript)
> [image]
> 2
> [{{ko:包}}山楚簡](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%85%E5%B1%B1%E6%A5%9A%E7%B0%A1)</kbd><kbd>秦
> 簡
> [image]
> 日書乙種17
> 睡虎地秦簡</kbd><kbd>今
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> **This should serve as an indication of how dramatically simple shapes can change.**

---

Chinese characters generally became *more complex* (**not** *more simple*) over time because (1) characters were often overloaded in usage and (2) shapes that were too simple were too easily confused with something else.「匕」is one of those components that you shouldn't take on face value, precisely because the shape is too simple, and several shapes that originally looked like something else have all converged into「匕」in the modern script.

As an actual *component which provides some sort of function upon character decomposition*,「匕」is a merger between two originally independent components which started to look extremely similar very early on.

---

**(1) Semantic *spoon* and/or phonetic** **ひ**

<kbd>商
甲
[image]
[甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)・355
[合集27578](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=27578&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
金
[image]
我方鼎
[集成2763](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2763&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

- 「[比]{ひ}」(*close/near, compare*), from doubly semantic and phonetic「[匕]{ひ}」(*spoon*), depicting two spoons side-by-side;

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [前7](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)・6.4
  [合集4240](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=4240&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>戰國・楚
  簡・帛
  [image]
  253
  {{ko:包}}山楚簡</kbd><kbd>秦
  簡
  [image]
  秦律十八21
  睡虎地秦簡</kbd><kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>
- 「旨」(*delicious*), from semantic「匕」(*spoon*) and semantic「口」(*mouth*) which later changed to「甘」(*sweet*), now looking like「曰」;

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)・1054
  [合集6828](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6828&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
  金
  [image]
  殳季良父壺
  [集成9713](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9713&jgwfl=)</kbd>
  <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
  [image]
  [旨部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=31)
  [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd><kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>
- 「[匙]{し}」(*spoon*), from semantic「匕」(*spoon*) and phonetic「[是]{し}」.

  <kbd>篆
  [image]
  [匕部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=12)
  說文解字</kbd><kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>

---

**(2) A shape variant of「人」(*person*) found on the right-hand-side of characters**

> Note:「比」is generally not confusable, at least originally, with「从」(*Shinjitai*:「従」).「从」is also a rare exception to the right-hand-side shape change of「人」.
>
> <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)・1124
> [合集10920](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=10920&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>商
> 金
> [image]
> 宰椃角
> [集成9105](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9105&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>戰國・楚
> 簡・帛
> [image]
> 忠信之道5
> 郭店楚簡</kbd><kbd>今
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>

- 「死」(*death*), from semantic「歹」(*picture of human remains* > *bad, wicked, evil*) and semantic「匕・人」(*person*);

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)・1165
  [合集17057](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=17057&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>戰國・楚
  簡・帛
  [image]
  42
  {{ko:包}}山楚簡</kbd><kbd>秦
  簡
  [image]
  為吏之道44
  睡虎地秦簡</kbd><kbd>[西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han)
  [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
  [image]

  [馬王堆帛書](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawangdui_Silk_Texts)</kbd><kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>
- 「北」(*back (anatomy)*, now written as「背」by adding on semantic「⺼・肉」*meat/flesh*), from semantic「匕・人」and its mirrored shape, depicting *two people back-to-back*;

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [菁](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)・2.1
  [合集6057](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6057&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>戰國・楚
  簡・帛
  [image]
  153
  {{ko:包}}山楚簡</kbd><kbd>秦
  簡
  [image]
  法174
  睡虎地秦簡</kbd><kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>
- 「此」(*to trample on something*, now written as「跐」by adding on semantic「足」*foot*), a compound of「止」(*picture of one foot* > *stop*) and a *person*「匕・人」.

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [戩](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)17.4
  [合集27499](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=27499&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
  金
  [image]
  亞此犧尊
  [集成5569](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=5569&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>秦
  簡
  [image]
  日乙139
  睡虎地秦簡</kbd><kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>

---

To finish off, here's some other examples of how **not** to decompose characters to produce what looks like「匕」:

1. Animals' legs.

   - 「鹿」(*deer*)

     <kbd>商
     甲
     [image]
     [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)265
     [合集33368](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=33368&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
     金
     [image]
     命簋
     [集成4112](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4112&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>秦
     簡
     [image]
     日甲75背
     睡虎地秦簡</kbd>
     <kbd>篆
     [image]
     [鹿部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=71)
     說文解字</kbd><kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
     隸
     [image]
     黽池五瑞碑</kbd>
     　<kbd>今
     楷
     [image]</kbd>
   - 「能」(*bear* > *power/strength* > *ability*)

     <kbd>西周
     金
     [image]
     能匋尊
     [集成5984](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=5984&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
     金
     [image]
     哀成叔鼎
     [集成2782](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2782&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>戰國・[晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_(Chinese_state))
     金
     [image]
     ⿰妾子壺
     [集成9734](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9734&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>秦
     簡
     [image]
     法150
     睡虎地秦簡</kbd><kbd>今
     楷
     [image]</kbd>
2. Body of a *snake*「它」, now written as「蛇」.

   <kbd>商
   甲
   [image]
   卷3・79
   戰後寧滬新</kbd><kbd>春秋
   金
   [image]
   子仲伯匜
   [集成10277](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=10277&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>戰國・楚
   簡・帛
   [image]
   164
   {{ko:包}}山楚簡</kbd><kbd>今
   楷
   [image]</kbd>
3. Corruption of *feet*「舛」in「乘」(*Shinjitai*:「乗」).

   <kbd>商
   甲
   [image]
   [粹](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)1109
   [合集6491](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6491&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
   金
   [image]
   公臣簋
   [集成4186](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4186&jgwfl=)</kbd>
   <kbd>篆
   [image]
   [桀部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=56)
   說文解字</kbd><kbd>今
   楷
   [image]</kbd>

   > 「乘」was originally a picture of a person「大」climbing on top of a tree「木」; feet「舛」were added on to the person later.
   >
   > The original meanings were to *ascend*, *to ride an object*, extended to mean *to take advantage of [a situation]*.